# Is it possible to halt an apt install, when the process is running?

Tags: apt

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, So forgive me of being ignorant about basic operations...

So let's say I tried to install a package, it takes too so, I want to abort it,

Is there a safe way of doing it, (preferably one that automatically deletes the files that get left, corrupted or unused packages etc.)

Comment: I install packages from terminal, which output lots of messages starting with the download of packages. If you ^C (ctrl+C or *sigint*) during this all files will be automatically deleted. If downloads have completed you'll see packages be installed (thru messages) and the system will attempt to correct itself anyway (ideally only press ^C once). If you press it (^C) too many times and interrupt the automatic cleanup-process (by killing it), you're only likely to need to `sudo apt-get install -f` (-f = `--fix-broken`) to correct things. It's pretty safe and you'll rarely need to *--fix-broken*